# Backbone.js custom constructor?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm looking for some examples for creating a custom constructor on my models. I want the structure the model/data differently then just setting it as attributes.

Can somebody show me some basic example of how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can transform the server's JSON as needed using `parse` (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse). Perhaps you should clarify what you're trying to do, an example might help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you really want to override the constructor, pass a `constructor` property to `Backbone.Model.extend()`, e.g.:

```
var Klass = Backbone.Model.extend( {

  constructor : function ( attributes, options ) {

    // ...

  }

} );
```

If you want to call the built-in constructor from your custom constructor, you can do something like:

```
var Klass = Backbone.Model.extend( {

  constructor : function ( attributes, options ) {

    Backbone.Model.apply( this, arguments );

  }

} );
```

Or if you don't want to have to repeat the name of the variable containing the parent class all over the sub class, or you don't want to worry about the value of that variable changing, you can do something like the following:

```
var Klass;

var parent_klass = Backbone.Model.prototype;

( function ( parent_klass ) {

  Klass = parent_klass.constructor.extend( {

    constructor : function ( attributes, options ) {

      parent_klass.constructor.apply( this, arguments );

    }

  } );

} )( parent_klass );
```

Or if you prefer the way [@Claude suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399334/backbone-js-custom-constructor/10413335#12347014), but repeating the sub class variable name within the sub class instead of the parent class var name:

```
var Klass = Backbone.Model.extend(

  {

    constructor : function ( attributes, options ) {

      Klass.parent_klass.constructor.apply( this, arguments );

    }

  },

  {

    parent_klass : Backbone.Model.prototype

  }

);
```

If you want more advice than that, you'll have to be more specific about what you want to accomplish.

Anything that you just want to do after the built-in constructor functionality, you should probably do in `initialize()`.

Comment: Be careful in using __super__ in combination with `this`. `this` will always point to the object being created, leading to an infinite loop. See my reply for more info.

Comment: @Claude yes, thanks for mentioning that. I've been meaning to update the answer re: that. I've stopped using `__super__` since posting this answer.

Comment: How about making a constructor for every instance of a model using prototype? I have been trying to modify the constructor method when an instance of Backbone.Model is created.  I want to perform some auto binding work with node's socket.io framework.  BuT I do not want to have to attach a constructor method to each model I create. Adding a prototype of initialize works; the only issue is if one is passed with the model it overrides it via the underscore extend method.

Answer (score 7):

As I mention in the comment, take care when using `this.constructor.__super__` (or `this.__super__`), lest you end up in an endless loop (`Maximum call stack size exceeded` in Chrome).

Try the following in the console (at own risk, it will lead to afore mentioned endless loop)

```
var A = Backbone.Model.extend({constructor: function () {
  console.log("log: A");
  this.constructor.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}});

var B = A.extend({constructor: function () {
  console.log("log: B");
  this.constructor.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}});

new A();
//  log: A
//  > Backbone.model.extend.constructor
new B();
//  log: B
//  (8192) log: A
//  > RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Reason is that when creating `B`, `this` in the constructor for `A` points to an instance of `B`, so `this.constructor.__super__.constructor` keeps pointing towards the constructor of `A`, which is being called time and time again.

If you want "intended behaviour", use one of the following syntaxes:

```
var A = Backbone.Model.extend({constructor: function () {
  console.log("log: A");
  A.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}});

var B = A.extend({constructor: function () {
  console.log("log: B");
  B.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}});

new A();
//  log: A
//  > Backbone.model.extend.constructor
new B();
//  log: B
//  log: A
//  > A.extend.constructor
```

or directly without `__super__`:

```
var A = Backbone.Model.extend({constructor: function () {
  console.log("log: A");
  Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
}});

var B = A.extend({constructor: function () {
  console.log("log: B");
  A.apply(this, arguments);
}});

new A();
//  log: A
//  > Backbone.model.extend.constructor
new B();
//  log: B
//  log: A
//  > A.extend.constructor
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how I override the default Backbone.Model constructor:

```
Backbone.Model = (function(Model) {
  // Define the new constructor
  Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    // Your constructor logic here
    // ...
    // Call the default constructor if you wish
    Model.apply(this, arguments);
    // Add some callbacks
    this.on('event', this.myCallback, this);
  };
  // Clone static properties
  _.extend(Backbone.Model, Model);      
  // Clone prototype
  Backbone.Model.prototype = (function(Prototype) {
    Prototype.prototype = Model.prototype;
    return new Prototype;
  })(function() {});
  // Update constructor in prototype
  Backbone.Model.prototype.constructor = Backbone.Model;
  return Backbone.Model;
})(Backbone.Model);
```

After that you have to make sure the Backbone.Collection prototype uses the updated Backbone.Model constructor:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Collection.prototype, {
  model: Backbone.Model
});
```

The 'advantage' of this approach in my opinion is that you can keep using Backbone.Model as your model constructor, which makes the change more transparent.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write your model by yourself, like this:

```
var YourModel = function () {
    // your constructor here
};

_.extend(YourModel.prototype, Backbone.Model.prototype, {
    // your model method here
});
```

Be careful, I think you need to consult `Backbone.Model` constructor [source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-28). But I think this is not a good idea. Override `initialize` method is the right way:

```
var YourModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function (attrs, options) {
        Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments); // call super constructor

        // your constructor code here
    }
});
```

Comment: The `Backbone.Model` initialize method is empty, not sure if there's any point in calling it.

Comment: @rane are you sure that will be the case in future releases? Definitely wise to call the super method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`initialize`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-constructor) method. It's called when you create a new model, and you can use if for whatever you need it for:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    // do something besides setting attributes or model
    alert('myModel is ready for action!');
  }
});

new myModel();
```

If you're looking to do something more involved, you might override the `constructor` method in Backbone core. That's a much trickier business, though. Much better to work with exposed methods if you can!

Comment: I'm looking for a custom constructor. I don't want attributes sent in to simply be set on the model. I'm looking to override the constructor.

Comment: You can of course pass an option hash to `initialize`, manipulate it within the function, and set whatever attributes you need from there.

Comment: `constructor` is "exposed", and the docs explain how you can override it.  `initialize` serves a different purpose.

Comment: Thanks, @Madbreaks. Much changes in five years!

Comment: @rjz - I didn't even notice how old your answer was!  :)

Answer (score -1):

Something to be aware of when overriding the Backbone.Model constructor - if you don't call `Backbone.Model.apply` then the Model.cid may not be set.

That's bad - If cid is not set across multiple models, collection may consider it to be a duplicate of the first model in your collection - and will not allow it to be added.