# What's the proper way to set a parent property in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a JSON file that will create my `ParentModel` as well as populate the child `Records` collection.

```
ParentModel : Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.set({ records: new Records(this.get("records")) });
  }
});
```

And the Records collection is just a basic Backbone collection that maps to a Record model.

The problem is that I need the child to know about the parent, so each `Record` model has to have a parent property on it. So for now I've just been adding this to the bottom of the initialize method:

```
var self = this;
this.get("records").each(function(record) {
  record.set("parent", self);
});
```

This works fine, but when I'm creating a new record I'd rather not have to remember to include those 4 lines.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10399476/74022) says I can override the initialize method to take in additional parameters, but I'm not quite sure how I would get Backbone to automatically pass in the ParentModel to the overridden initialize method. Can anyone provide an example on how to do that?

I've heard of [Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) which might help do what I want, but that's another 23kb to include. If that's the better way to go I'll look at implementing it, but otherwise I'd prefer a simpler solution if one is available.

This needs to work whether I create a new `ParentModel` record through code, or if it's being automatically created by a JSON feed.

Comment: I posted a solution,but after rereading your question, I realized  that wasn't the answer you were looking for. I don't think there's a solution that wouldn't add complexity to your code. But if you really wanted to do this, I think the best place to override would be the Records collection; overriding initialize to check for and set a parent option, then the add function to set a parent for each new model you add to the collection.

Comment: @Brandon Hoping the records are added to Collection. each model will now have a `collection` property that can be accessed using `model.collection` may be this tip will help you

Comment: @AnthonyChua, that would work when adding a new Record through code, but how can I make sure that the overridden initialize method is used when populating the models from a JSON feed?

Comment: @Brandon If you populate the collection via the usual `fetch()` call, the collection just actually calls the `reset` or `add` function depending on your passed option. And even though `collection.fetch` calls `reset` by default, `reset` is still going to use `add` to populate the collection.

Comment: Can you explain why you need a reference to `Records` collection in every `Record` model? This seems odd.

Comment: @yvesamsellem, I don't need a reference to the collection in the Record model, I need a reference to ParentModel from the Record model.

Comment: @yvesamsellem, the way we're using it the children need to know certain properties of the parent and properties of the other elements in the collection in order to position themselves on an SVG element. For example, if I wanted to center position a Record element, I'd need to know how wide the viewbox is. The only way to know that is to know what the widest record element is. The parent object can tell me that by sorting through its child elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually find that moving the structural elements out of the attributes is cleaner so my records and parent properties are on the object, not the attributes. That said, you could take advantage of the different events on the collection and the parent object:

```
var ParentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'adoptOne', 'adoptAll');
        this.records = new Records();

        this.on('change:records', function () {
             this.records.reset(this.get('records'));
        });
        this.records.on('reset', this.adoptAll);
        this.records.on('add', this.adoptOne);

        this.records.reset(this.get('records'));
    },

    adoptAll: function () {
       this.records.each(this.adoptOne);
    },
    adoptOne: function (model) {
        model.parent = this;
    }
});
```

A few tests :

```
var p = new ParentModel({
    name: "I am the parent",
    records: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
});

p.records.add({id: 3});

p.records.each(function (child) {
    console.log(child.get('id')+' '+child.parent.get('name'));
});

p.set({records: [{id: 4}]});

p.records.each(function (child) {
    console.log(child.get('id')+' '+child.parent.get('name'));
});
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sPXaZ/

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, here is a summary of one of your needs (*which can be find in the question comments*):

> For example, if I wanted to center position a Record element, I'd need
>   to know how wide the viewbox is. The only way to know that is to know
>   what the widest record element is. The parent object can tell me that
>   by sorting through its child elements.

It seems to me that your Model have to handle display problematic; display in Backbone is handled by Views. So, I guess you can create a View which listen to both `ParentModel` and `Records`.

```
var RecordView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this);
  }
  render: function() {
    var widest = this.model.get('width');
  }
});

var view = new RecordView({model: ParentModel, collection: Records});
```

And, in my opinion, this is not to the `ParentModel` to handle the width it take on screen but to its own View. Introducing two Views here seems to be the point.

But I've not the full picture, so, please, if I'm wrong, give me more samples of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I realize the model shouldn't have to handle display issues, but in reality the `width` is part of the model itself. The models are mapped to SVG elements stored in the database, but I see what you're saying. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Even if the `width` is a part of your `Model`, I would highly encourage you to use Backbone framework as it meant to be. Twisting a framework in a way it was not immagine can lead you to several headaches. My advice would be: rely on the `Model` and `Collection` attributes into a proper `View`. `Model` would be in charge of the HTTP requests, `View` would be in charge of the display. Don't you think it will be easier?