# Refer model from collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I am using Backbone to structure my web application, this is my situation:

```
Section = Backbone.Model.extend({
     initialize: function(){
          this.set("elements", new ElementCollection());
     }
})

ElementCollection = Backbone.Model.extend({

     model: ElementModel

})
```

The meaning of this relation is that `Section` contains multiple `Elements`. 
My goal now is to refer, from a `ElementCollection` to its parent `Section` model.

How can I achieve this?

I tried to `set` a `property` in the `Collection`, like:

```
this.set("parentSection", theParentSection")
```

but this does not do the trick, in fact the standard `set` method in a Collection adds a model inside it, which breaks all my structure.

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11417645/1071630 ?

Comment: That could be a solution. What I want to do is to refer model from collection and not from every model inside it

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parent model to the collection when initializing it:

```
Section = Backbone.Model.extend({
     initialize: function(){
          this.set("elements", new ElementCollection([], {parentModel: this}));
     }
})

ElementCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     initialize: function (options) {
         this.parentSection = options.parentModel;
     }, 
     model: ElementModel
})
```